# Convert part of string to double with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, double, type-conversion

My application seem crash on "wrong format", I have this:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(value, "[0-9]+[.[0-9]+]?");
double number = Convert.ToDouble(m.Value);
return number;
```

Point is to make string values like this: `114.6W, 120.6W.` into values I can sort. 
My function that I wrote is suppose to turn any string into a 9999.9999 double value, but it crash on `Convert.ToDouble()`. Saying wrong input format?

Comment: Why can't you sort "114.6W" and "120.6W"?

Comment: I guess I could, but I would like to make it a number value and then sort..

Comment: @paul the [string "114" is < "14" and < "24"](http://ideone.com/uMhnSS), so you can't simply sort by strings if the OP actually needs to sort by value.

Comment: @Link yes, I assumed leading zeroes

Comment: Please view [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/213671) to understand why I have edited your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `.` is not the decimal separator for the culture you are using. Try specifying `InvariantCulture` when parsing:

```
double number = Convert.ToDouble(m.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your regex: it should read

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

`[.[0.9]+]` (which I am surprised parses at all) is a character class looking for any character in the following set: a dot, an opening and closing bracket, 0 to 9, or a plus sign.

Comment: In C# I get "unrecognized escape character". Regex is giving me a headace

Comment: With what? Your original regex or the proposed one?

Answer (score 0):

You must replace square brackets by parenthesis

```
Match m = Regex.Match(value, @"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed to always be a decimal number followed by a single letter, then:

```
var word = "120.6W";
var d = Decimal.Parse(word.Substring(0,word.Length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two regexes, you may need to test and adjust to your needs

this one will grab all numbers including the `.`, but only if followed by a **W** (won't grab the w)

```
(?i)\d+\.\d+(?=w)
```

this one will grab all the digits regardless what's after it

```
\d+\.\d+
```

or if your data sets consists of only the numbers plus one letter and nothing in front or after it, do as @paul suggests, just strip the last char

Comment: Beware, there's a trap: `\d` in .NET will match _any UTF-8 digit_. It is not limited to 0-9.